# import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

Tags: webdriver

Can anyone tell me, what are these following lines used for in selenium, and the other import commands and there uses
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver is a tool for automating testing web applications, and in particular to verify that they work as expected.

The driver comes in the form of an xpi (firefox extension) which is added to the firefox profile when you start a new instance of FirefoxDriver. To use FirefoxDriver Firefox must be installed on machine and be in the normal location for OS.

You can find detailed information and example codes [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Lafontein